# Why are these representations of e the same?

Tags: definition, exponential-function

I heard that $e$ can be defined as the limit as n approaches infinity of $(1 + 1/n)^n$, but I also heard that $e$ is also defined as the sum of the reciprocals of the factorials from $0$ to $\infty$. How are these the same?

Comment: Iyengar has answered this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99016/proof-that-e-sum-limits-k-0-infty-frac1k)

Comment: See [equivalence of the characterizations of the exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_the_characterizations).

Answer (score 0):

Let's find an infinite polynomial $p(x)$ having $p(0) = 1$ and $\frac{d}{dx}p(x) = p(x)$.  We know that the constant term must be 1, and the coefficient of $x^1$ must be 1.  After a little reflection, it's easy to see that 
$$p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!}$$
This must be the only continuous function having these two properties.

Now let's look at the limit

$$L(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} L(x) 
& = \frac{d}{dx} \left\{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right\}\\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d}{dx} \left\{\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right\}\\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{d}{dx} \left\{1 + \frac{x}{n}\right\}n\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\\
\end{align}$$

So:

$$\begin{align}
L(x) - \frac{d}{dx}L(x) & = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}-\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}-\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\left(\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)-1\right)\right)\\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-
1}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right)\\
& = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\left(0\right)\right)\\
L(x) - \frac{d}{dx}L(x) & = 0
\end{align}$$
So $L(x) = \frac{d}{dx}L(x)$, $L(0) = 1$, and $L$ is a continuous function.  So $L(x) = p(x)$, and specifically $L(1) = p(1) = e$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: use the binomial theorem

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Notice the word "Hint" as a preface.

Comment: @Dr.MV I noticed. This is what I do with hints.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Perhaps there is a more constructive approach.  I suggest posting an answer rather than taking time to accrue "down votes." I neutralized the down vote.