# Does $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If I try on a few examples, I see that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$ never goes beyond $1$.

How can I prove it has a limit?

Comment: Hint: Infinite summation of gemetric series is given by $${a\over 1-r}$$

Comment: $\sum\frac{1}{2^n}$ has little meaning if you do not declare which values of $n$ are considered. $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^n}=2 > 1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio fixed, thank you

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't see why my question is "off-topic" while this one is not: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99016/proof-that-e-sum-limits-k-0-infty-frac1k?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}= \frac {1/2}{1-1/2}=1$$ is a special case of the geometric series $$ a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+... = \frac {a}{1-r}$$ for $|r|<1$

Comment: Thank you Mohammad

Comment: @Paul Thank you for your attention and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum \frac{1}{2^n} = \sum \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n = \frac{1}{1-1/2} = 2 $$